# how to delete all contents of existing TFS folder & checkin a new project in the same folder?

Tags: version-control, tfs

I see an option on TFS to get the latest code from TFS Server to local system.

[image]

Is there an option to do vice versa ? I converted a windows forms application to an asp.net application. I would like to use the same tfs folder to replace all my windows forms code with my asp.net code.
I would like to delete everything under a tfs source code folder and update entirely new code in that folder from my local box.  Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete from Source Control Explorer in VS (you will need to have the latest version locally first). Then you can Add new items, again from Source Control Explorer.

When you delete, do a check-in before you add your new items to make it easier for TFS to process. You might have good reason for it but I would seriously consider adding your new solution as a new folder as it is essentially a new application. It will be easier to view history of your legacy app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to permanently delete winform code files from Team Foundation version control, you need to choose to use [tf destroy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005(v=vs.100).aspx) command. 
Like:

tf destroy $/project/winform/form1.cs

Then add ASP.NET project to that folder.